# create-react-app returns an Error: Cannot find module 'react-scripts/scripts/init.js' when executed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

when I try to create a react project with both npm and yarn, it shows me the following error:

I tried to reinstall node and make sure it was up to date, as well as create-react-app by running npm install -g create-react-app@latest. I also removed the npm and npm-cache folders and the environment variable, but nothing works for me and I keep getting the same error.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react-scripts/scripts/init.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at [eval]:2:20
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:122:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:329:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at evalScript (internal/bootstrap/node.js:589:27)

Aborting installation.
  node  has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting test/ from C:\Users\Esper\projects
Done.
```

I think the problem arose from restoring my windows 10 to a previous state due to operating system problems, because before restoring it, when I run create-react-app it worked correctly.

create-react-app --version
3.1.1

node -v
v10.16.3

npm -v
6.9.0

SO
Windows 10 Education

Comment: You get the error when you try to generate a new project or while launching an already existing project ?

Comment: when i try to create a brand new project

Comment: and what command do you use to create new project ? `npx create-react-app your-app` ?

Comment: yes, neither `npx create-react-app your-app` or `create-react-app your-app` works

Comment: have you tried `npm uninstall create-react-app` before re-installing it ?

Comment: yes, i tried uninstalling create-react-app, also node and yarn completely and then reinstall them again, but I didn't get any results.

Comment: Ok so you got Yarn also. Can you check that yarn is relative to yarnpkg in your Path because there is also a yarn for java and it can cause trouble. There was an issue for this in github but i don't know if they fix it or not.

Comment: You have something called yarn on your system which is a Java program.
Create React App thinks it is Yarn package manager and attempts to use it instead of npm.

As a temporary workaround you can remove yarn from your path.

Comment: I have been 6 years working with nodejs, and this dumbest thing from nodejs does always happen. Not only nodejs I work with, Java server, php server, and many server, but others seem never have problem that happen again and again and again like this dumbest of nodejs. It is fast? No it wasted time.

Comment: ok, by that time the only solution was to switch to my usual operating system which was linux. But I think the problem may be related to the Yarn package that @Jon mentions.

Answer (score 4):

Install a package.json with `npm init` (press enter till is installed)
After that install react-scripts with `npm i react-scripts`,
Then you can install react with `npx create-react-app your-app`.
Change the directory to *"your-app"*
Run again `npm i react-scripts` and it should work.

Hope I did not missed a step, let me know if works :)

Answer (score 0):

Just run this code on git bash:

```
npm install
npm install react-scripts
npx create-react-app your-app-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help somebody else.

This error can happen after you use create-react-app in case you have some invalid character in your path.

Remove charecteres like `&` from your path.

For example, change from this:

```
C:\Users\...\Documents\Section 3 Components & Start\my-app
```

To this:

```
C:\Users\...\Documents\Section 3 Components Start\my-app
```